# How do you do? vs Hello

Tags: meaning

I would like to know whether "How do you do?" Must be used to say "nice to meet you?" Or whether there is a case that we can use "how do you do?" As a replacement of "hello". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it if you like, but it is rather formal. See [How are you vs How do you do](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107265/how-are-you-vs-how-do-you-do) and related questions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the context.

*How do you do?* is formal, and it is most often used when first meeting someone.

Yes, there is definitely a time and place to pull it out of your lexical toolbox.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "yes, there is definitely a time and place to pull it out of your lexical toolbox." Do you mean that "how do you do?" Can be used to replace "hello". For example, when conversing with someone you already met?

Comment: @Student  It is possible to use "how do you do?" for someone you have already met...  perhaps you first met them ten years ago.  The point is about formality.  "How do you do?" is definitely formal.  It is to be used in a formal context--at least in American English.

Comment: All right, I understand now that "how do you do?" Is used in a formal context but what remains to me is whether it might be used to replace "hello". I have noticed that many people use it to replace "nice to meet you!" So, I would like to be sure that whether how do you do?" Can replace "hello"?

Comment: @Student   Yes, it can be used to "replace" hello, but this is not the right way to look at it.  "Hello" has one context, and "How do you do?" has another...  for greeting.  "How do you do?" is most commonly used when meeting someone for the first time--but not exclusively.

Comment: Okay, It is clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Ironically, the abbreviated form "howdy" is not formal in most places, as far as I know. Wikipedia says, "In the rural Southwestern United States, Howdy is a colloquial contraction of the formal greeting of How do you do?, and as such is considered a formal and acceptable greeting" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howdy), but The Free Dictionary says it's "an informal, colloquial greeting" (https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/howdy).